# How To Inherit Parent Directories Group

Tags: linux, directory, file-permissions

I have a directory `/applications` which is owned by `root` and group `git`.

The problem is when I create a new directory inside /applications, its owned by root and group root, not group git. How do I make new directories inside /applications inherit the group git instead of root?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable setgid on it:

```
chmod g+s /applications
```

From that point all the files and directories will be owned by group `git`